# Weblogic KeyStore Service Exception: Failed to perform cryptographic operation

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

I tried to start Weblogic and I'm getting the exception below:

> There are 1 nested errors:
>
> oracle.security.jps.JpsException:
>   oracle.security.jps.service.keystore.KeyStoreServiceException: Failed
>   to perform cryptographic operation
>           at oracle.security.jps.internal.config.OpssCommonStartup.preStart(OpssCommonStartup.java:418)
>           at oracle.security.jps.JpsStartup.preStart(JpsStartup.java:358)
>           at oracle.security.jps.wls.JpsBootStrapService.start(JpsBootStrapService.java:80)
>           at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my version of JDK, and then it was right.

> 1- remove JDK 1.8 update 40
>
> 2- install JDK 1.8 update 1.8.0_221